# Reordering triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone please help me understand how to solve this question?
[image]

I think that maybe the limits for x are 0 and 6 but I'm not sure and I don't know how to find the other limits

Thank you so much

Comment: I suggest that you first try to swap the integrals with x and z and then swap the integrals with x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the inner two limits then the outer two limits as Mosquite suggests is probably best.
$$
\int_0^\sqrt{6}\!\int_0^\sqrt{6-y^2}\!\int_{y^2+z^2}^6f\;dxdzdy = \int_0^\sqrt{6}\!\int_{y^2}^6\int_{0}^\sqrt{x-y^2}f\;dzdxdy = \int_0^6\int_{0}^\sqrt{x}\!\int_{0}^\sqrt{x-y^2}f\;dzdxdy
$$
Both of the swaps use the identity
$$
(0 \le s \le \sqrt{6-a^2})\cap (s^2+a^2\le t \le 6) = (a^2 \le t\le 6)\cap (0\le s\le \sqrt{t-a^2})
$$
which you should try working out for yourself.